# Symfony : how to dynamically include assets and defer their loading at the end of the page?

Tags: php, performance, symfony, load, assets

working on a Symfony PHP CMS-based project, I'm having assets loading questions.

We created several types of widgets available in content management. That allows contributors to add one or several widget on their pages. Each type of widget has its own styles and scripts.

In actual state, we load every widgets assets at the end of the page **even if the page does not contain each type of widget.**

In order to optimize page weight and loading, we'd like to have a mecanism that add a call to one widget assets (during the widget rendering) and defer their loading at the end of the page.

Do you know a tool that could do the job ?

Not possible to show the whole code, but in short, here is what I'd like to do :

```
<body>
  <article>
    <widget_one>// I need @widget_one assets</widget_one>
    <widget_two>// I need @widget_two assets</widget_one>
    .....
    .....
  </article>
  <assets>// now I load all needed assets</assets>
</body>
```

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I came up with you can use Using Named Assets:

```
# app/config/config.yml
 assetic:
   assets:
      widget_one:
         inputs:
             - '@AppBundle/Resources/public/js/widget_one_first_js.js'
             - '@AppBundle/Resources/public/js/widget_one_second_js.js'
      widget_two:
         inputs:
             - '@AppBundle/Resources/public/js/widget_two_first_js.js'
             - '@AppBundle/Resources/public/js/widget_two_second_js.js'
```

After that in your template you use it -> if you have widget_one

```
{% javascripts
   '@widget_one'
    <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

if you have widget_one

```
 {% javascripts
   '@widget_two'
    <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

You should use template inheritance: For example base.html.twig

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>{% block title %}Welcome!{% endblock %}</title>
{% block stylesheets %}{% endblock %}
</head>
 <body>
 {% block body %}{% endblock %}
 {% block javascripts %}{% endblock %}
 </body>
</html>
```

After that:

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

{% block javascripts %}
  {% for widget in widgets   %}
    INCLUDE ASSETS   
  {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
{% block body %}    
 {% for widget in widgets   %}
    SHOW WIDGET!    
 {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Great to associate assets with each type of widget !

Now, how can I load them at the end of my page ? I mean, with your solution, assets blocks will be rendered in the body of the page, in the rendering of each widget template. I would like these assets to be loaded at the end of the page.